# Position button relatively to the content

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

*I am using Angular Material.* I need to pin FAB button in bottom center of my content like:
[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
<div>
  <md-button class="md-warn">
    Remove all
  </md-button>
  <md-button class="md-primary" style="float:right">
    Compare
  </md-button>
</div>

</div>
<md-button class="md-fab md-primary" style="position:relative; left:50%; margin-left:-20px; margin-bottom:-27px">
  <md-icon style="color:#fff" class="material-icons">add</md-icon>
</md-button>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

As you see, distance between `REMOVE` and `COMPARE` buttons and content border is bigger, cause the length of FAB button included.

How can I get my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you need to put all three `md-button` elements into one row with `layout-align="space-between center"`. Hope this is what you are expecting:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGBjdO